# Accessing contacts in outlook / exchange through VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing a Outlook add-in that needs to access Outlook contacts.  I have successfully obtained a list of local contacts but cant seem to find an example that will give me access to the list of shared contacts using VSTO.

Comment: Did it not work? The lack of OP response is sometimes a bit strange for Outlook related questions...

Answer (score 2):

```
Application
  .GetNamespace("MAPI")
  .AddressLists["Global Address List"]
  .AddressEntries
```

Comment: I'm not OP but I used the snippet. You've got a type there, though. Apparently MS sees namespace as one word and has no capital letter on "space" part.   :)